# Amazon SNS: how to get token for confirm subscription

Tags: python-2.7, boto, amazon-sns

Following creates a subscription waiting to be confirmed.

```
aws_client.subscribe(TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol=protocol, Endpoint=endpoint)
```

response of this is something like:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '298',
   'content-type': 'text/xml',
   'date': 'Fri, 13 Oct 2017 10:15:47 GMT',
   'x-amzn-requestid': '7a0a40fb-ab72-5584-94f0-12a13fe11das'},
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'RequestId': '7a0a40fb-ab72-5584-94f0-12a13fe11das',
  'RetryAttempts': 0},
 u'SubscriptionArn': 'pending confirmation'}
```

above response did not send any token.
How to get the token which can be passed to confirm_subscription as stated [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.confirm_subscription)

Comment: It seems like you haven't confirmed (the email of) your account or your payment information at AWS. This would `pending conformation` mean to me in your context.

Comment: Have you succeeded this step? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.confirm

Comment: once i subscribe for email endpoint, i got email for confirmation and it works fine from there.

Comment: What kind of subscription is being created, here?

Comment: subscription for email protocol.

Comment: Hi, @navyad did you find a solution to this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems, the Token is not available from inside the response of the `subscribe` command itself. Rather, as [mentioned in the Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.confirm_subscription), the token is

> "...***sent to the endpoint*** by an earlier Subscribe action." (***emphasis*** mine)

The [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/confirm-subscription.html) states the same thing, but a little bit more clearly perhaps:

> "Short-lived token ***sent to an endpoint*** during the subscribe action." (***emphasis*** mine)

In other words, for an Email Endpoint, the Token is in the email itself. You can see it if you look at the URL for the "Confirm subscription" Link.

For example, it will look something like https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/confirmation.html?TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:my-aws-topic&Token=abc123&Endpoint=address@email.com

Here in this example, you can see the Token would be **abc123**.