# sns: How do I obtain a token in order to confirm a subscription using boto?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sns

I'm using boto3 to create a topic, create a subscription to that topic and then confirm that subscription, but I'm a little confused on how to do the final part.

My code looks something like this:

```
client = boto3.client('sns')

def create_topic():

    topic = client.create_topic(Name='TopicName')
    return topic['TopicArn']

def create_subscription(arn=''):

    subscription = client.subscribe(
        TopicArn=arn,
        Protocol='https',
        Endpoint='https://foo.com/endpoint'
        ReturnSubscriptionArn=True
    )
```

running `create_subscription()` with a valid topicArn gives me the following response body:

```
{'SubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:12345678911:foo:0e123205-b1f5-992b-9da1-340ace03a3ca',
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1879a45a-7b1c-51bb-c65c-11d94111594c',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '1937c57a-8b9a-51ba-b88d-56d88458533a',
   'content-type': 'text/xml',
   'content-length': '379',
   'date': 'Tue, 19 Jun 2018 17:00:03 GMT'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I then thought the token I needed to confirm the sub was the `RequestId` key in the metadata dict i.e.

```
token = response['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']

resource = boto3.resource('sns')
topic = resource.Topic(TopicArn)
topic.confirm_subscription(
    Token=token
)
```

But with the above I get an invalid token error.

The boto3 docs just say the following:

> Request Syntax
>
> subscription = topic.confirm_subscription(
>       Token='string',
>       AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe='string' ) Parameters Token (string) -- [REQUIRED]
>
> Short-lived token sent to an endpoint during the Subscribe action.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Topic.confirm_subscription

When it says 'Subscribe action' i assumed it was returned in the subscribe body i.e. why I did the above

I am missing something probably obvious here, but I can't seem to get my head around what exactly.

Comment: Please look at [Amazon SNS: how to get token for confirm subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728286/amazon-sns-how-to-get-token-for-confirm-subscription) for an existing answer that should help. The token is in the actual notification body.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with code, something like `if sns.confirmed(): sns.publish else: sns.subscribe()`.  Did you ever find a way to get this token?

Comment: I think the token would come in the request if you have set sns permission. I have the same problem and could not find the answer yet. But I am trying it.