# AWS SNS- how do I retrieve a token for confirm_subscription

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm writing a python 3.7 script to direct SNS messages to an SQS queue. 
After creating the queue and the topic, I'm trying to subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic by calling sns.subscribe:

```
sns = boto3.client('sns')
subscription = sns.subscribe(
    TopicArn=sns_topic,
    Protocol='sqs',
    Endpoint=sqs_queue_arn,
    ReturnSubscriptionArn=True )
```

According to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe):

> To actually create a subscription, the endpoint owner must call the ConfirmSubscription action with the **token** from the confirmation message.

The documentation for [confirm_subscription](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.confirm_subscription) asks for the **token** from the subscribe call:

> Verifies an endpoint owner's intent to receive messages by validating the token sent to the endpoint by an earlier Subscribe action

```
    sns.confirm_subscription(
        TopicArn=sns_topic,
        Token= **????????????**
    )
```

The problem is that the first call to subscribe does not ask for, neither returns a token.

Any idea how do I retrieve the token?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using boto3 (1.16.52), Django (3.1.5), and python-dotenv (0.15.0).  I was able to confirm the subscription with this little script in my POST controller.

```html
#convert body from request in JSON to python dict (Here is the token)
data=json.loads(request.body)
#Access SNS from boto3
sns = boto3.resource('sns',region_name='us-east-1')
#Access with python-dotenv the arn of my topic from my .env file 
#(you can get it from AWS console, is something like arn:aws:sns:region:number:topic )
sns_arn=os.getenv("SNS_ARN")
#get topic
topic = sns.Topic(sns_arn)
#Confirm suscription
if "Token" in data.keys(): 
    topic.confirm_subscription(Token=data["Token"])
    print("confirmation success",flush=True)
```

Don't forget to create and save your .env file with your own SNS_ARN variable.
For more info about environment variables check:
[python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)
and boto3:
[boto3 confirm_suscription](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.confirm_subscription)

Answer (score 0):

I found out there was no need for it.

The reason why I did not get messages on my SQS queue from the SNS topic was that it was lacking permissions as described in step 2  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html).

Note that handling confirmation is different if the SNS topic and SQS queue are not in the same account, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-message-to-sqs-cross-account.html)

Comment: Good to know you found an answer. In your case, because you used SQS, the confirmation was handled automatically by AWS. If you had an email or https endpoint external to AWS, AWS would send a message to that endpoint with the token, and the endpoint would make the `confirm_subscription` call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728286/amazon-sns-how-to-get-token-for-confirm-subscription

Comment: Thanks @bimsapi.

I'll won't delete the question for the sake of documentation